# Listbox item in pivot control doesn't get all available space

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, layout

I have simple page with pivot control and listbox inside, but I cannot make listbox to stretch to get all available space.

Templates:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <converter:UserMessageConverter x:Key="MessageUserConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,30">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Text}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"  FontSize="21.333" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding User, Converter={StaticResource MessageUserConverter}}" Margin="12,3,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18.667"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WindowsPhone.Application.ViewModel.MessageListViewModel">
        <ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}" Background="Aqua">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <wi:Interaction.Triggers>
                <wi:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <wi:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MessageSelectedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=MessageList}" />
                </wi:EventTrigger>
            </wi:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Pivot:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <!--Pivot Control-->
<controls:Pivot Title="Messages &amp; Responses" ItemsSource="{Binding Pages}">
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <helpers:DataTemplateSelector Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
</Grid>
```

[image: The result which I got]

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but give this a try

```
 <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate>
                  <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
              </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
  </Style>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Watch to [this](http://timdams.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/creating-a-wp7-app-listbox-items-of-the-same-width/), but I think that `ListBox` is stretched the whole parent container but the parent doesn't. Why aqua box is on the center on the page and not on the left or top? Please, try make the same app but without templated `Pivot`, maybe it push you to right direction and you find where the issue

Comment: If I use non-templated Pivot, it works well, the issue happens only when I use templates for Pivot item